# Resources for Kids Learning C#

Tags: c#

My 11 year old son is very interested in programming. He has been working with [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu)
for a couple years but has now outgrown it. I recently helped him install Visual C# Express Edition and he is very excited to work with it, but we're having a hard time finding good resources for him online.

He learns best by looking at sample programs, dissecting them, altering them, etc. Searching around I wasn't able to find many good samples for him to download and try in C# Express Edition. Can anyone point me in the direction of a good set of sample programs for a kid learning C#, or any other resources you think might be good for him?

BTW I'm a programmer myself but I've been almost exclusively working with Linux for a long time, so when it comes to Microsoft I'm pretty lost!

Comment: Your question is similar to this - but I like your wording better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133/programming-for-a-9-year-old#37253

Comment: Thanks, I have an eight year old as well. He's just getting into scratch but I think he might like some of the other things mentioned in that thread. I don't know if he's got the drive, but I want to make sure he's got the tools at hand if he does.

Comment: I had great success introducing my daughter to programming in C# by basically following this course: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/teaching-kids-programming. It's a free pluralsight course that shows parents/teachers how to work through a C# version of a Teaching Kids Programming exercise. I used it last year for Take Your Daughter to Work Day and it interesting another co-worker's daughter as well, so I ended up teaching it to both of them. My daughter was 7 and the other girl was maybe 11, but I think this work well for just about anyone as long as they can use the keyboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend [Coding4Fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/).  There are some very nice projects out there which would appeal to an 11 year old.  I recall seeing some games, screensavers, and even a sample which shows how to make a WinForms app look like it is bleeding (awesome for Halloween, eh?)

Answer (score 3):

Hmm... given that C# isn't really a "teaching language" (and that's not to say it's a bad choice), I suspect there aren't a lot of tutorials targeted at younger kinds.  Have you considered doing some parallel learning and trying to pick up C# with your son?  It might be a good bonding experience for both of you, and with your background in programming, you'll likely have a lot of insight to share, even if it's more language agnostic knowledge about things like algorithms, style, commenting, pitfalls to avoid, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If your son has already been working with Scratch and is going to be starting on C# then I would say that he is ready for a regular starting C# tutorial. Teaching programming to kids in general has been discussed several times at SO a few times. Here is one of the better results ([How and when do you teach a kid to code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165905/how-and-when-do-you-teach-a-kid-to-code)). The principal concepts of teaching a kid to program are the same regardless of the language.

Comment: Yep, the question was (rightfully so) closed just as this one was.

Answer (score 2):

[Alice](http://www.alice.org/) is based around story-telling.  It's not programming specifically, but it teaching programming mechanisms.  Instead of loop, it's more like "Repeat this" type construct.  Worth watching the demo video though.

Answer (score 2):

I just found when zapping the web the [Kid's Corner from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb308754.aspx), he could have a go on this link as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Code Project is a good resource, but many of the sample are more complicated than you'd want to start with.

For smaller sample apps, Microsoft released their [101 Samples for Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2005/aa718334.aspx)

[XNA](http://creators.xna.com/) is cool, but is somewhat complicated to get started with.

[Coding4Fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/) is also good, but the amount of content isn't that huge.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would love than my daughter would be interest in programming when she come to that age, and for that, congratulations.

Microsoft has [Codding 4 Fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/) which should be a nice start, and if he's interested in Video tutorials, check the [ASP.NET Learn website](http://www.asp.net/learn), he will find a lot of tutorials and video tutorials in VB and C# together with all the source code.

After that, [code Project](http://www.codeproject.com) is a nice place to look to more examples :)

Good programming!

Answer (score 1):

Any book written in or after 2008 that states it's C# for beginners on Amazon with positive reviews. Do *not* buy |BLANK| for dummies, no kid likes it! and keep a maximum price of $30 for $25 you can get a book that will be so great Microsoft might have to hire him, lol jk. i recommend a wrox book but any other book will do. has he coded any program yet, is he doing freeware, opensource or paid. some books are made especially for open source. it might be hard at first, but he will end up coding some really useful programs. Main thing, make him keep going! don't let him quit. In my opinion, it isn't worth quitting; once you got the hang of it coding is really fun.

Answer (score 1):

For an absolute beginner I would suggest [www.codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com).  It is very simply written and completely interactive from the very first page load.  Very ideal for a 1st timer imho.  It teaches in JavaScript not C# but they are pretty similar as far as syntax goes.  He might already be too advanced for this though.

Answer (score 1):

I've started with C# by joining a Minecraft ([link](http://www.minecraft.net)) classic server development team. These were all people around 16+, but they really helped me learning the language. Getting into a team with people around your age who are a bit more experienced helps a lot I think, and I'd definitely recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/) comes to mind. Lots of samples, projects, etc. available to play with.

Answer (score 0):

If games interested him (which is a fair bet) check out [XNA](http://creators.xna.com/), otherwise try to find some other interest, for example music, and then look for a framework/SDK that would let you create useful content quickly without having to do too much legwork.

Comment: Thanks. We did pull down XNA but it's a bit too much for him at this point. He definitely wants to create flashy games, but understands he needs to master the basics first. I have no doubt he'll eventually tackle XNA, then he'll be asking for an Xbox 360!

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in checking out [Popfly](http://www.popfly.com/Home.aspx). It is a system similar to Scratch but if you want you can begin adding your own components or do some extra javascript or C#. The integration of the multiple technologies might be a little too advanced but then again it might be okay. Again this is very close to Scratch but it might be fun.

As mentioned previously definitely check out Coding4Fun.

Congratulations and good luck.